# Setting the title on a Javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, html

I want to reset the title of a popup window (HTML, Javascript), I know this problem has been discussed, but I can't find a solid solution.  You should be able to set the title using "document.title" but it resets to the page title after load.  My production code loads a .txt file, and the path is showing up in the titlebar as the title, but in my example we're loading CNN.  Here's a example to work with.  Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/2cr9oh8h/12/

```
<form id="statementForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="userid">
  <input type="hidden" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Change" onclick="doBalanceSheet()">
</form>

function doBalanceSheet() {

  var statementForm = document.getElementById('statementForm');
  var window_name = 'window_' + (new Date()).getTime();
  statementForm.method = "POST";     
  statementForm.userid.value = 'test'; 
  statementForm.password.value = 'test';             
  var w = window.open('', window_name, 'width=1100,height=600,resizeable,scrollbars');
  statementForm.action="../test.txt";    
  statementForm.target = window_name;  
  statementForm.submit();

  w.document.title = 'New Title';
}
```

Comment: Because of the same-origin policy, you're not allowed to modify `document.title` on pages that resides on a different origin.

Comment: This might be helpful for you [Same Origin Policy](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Comment: It loads the results of a local Perl script, I only used the cnn.com domain as an example.

Comment: Use Bootstrap modals. It's the solution 100% trust me.

Comment: Then you need to create an event handler for the pop-up window's `load` event or `DOMContentLoaded` event and set the title in that handler